# Limit within a limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives

Hey can someone please show me a step by step procedure to show that the below is possible. I can't seem to figure out how to reduce a limit within a limit to a single limit and the replacing of the variable 'a' and 'b' with 'c'

(Someone mentioned iterated limits but I'm not sure how to exactly show that)

$$\lim_{a\to 0}\dfrac{\lim\limits_{b\to 0}\dfrac{{f(x+a+b)-2f(x+b)+f(x)}}{b}}{a}=\lim_{c\to 0}\frac{{{f(x+2c)-2f(x+c)+f(x)}}}{c^2}$$

This idea is used when proving the Grunwald-Letkinov derivative ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GrünwaldLetnikov_derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCnwaldLetnikov_derivative)) and they mentioned that this step is done by assuming that both 'a' and 'b' converge synchronously and can be justified by MVT. If possible could you explain that? and how would I use MVT to justify this.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the upper numerator as and assuming $f$ is derivable then:

$\underbrace{\dfrac{f(x+a+b)-f(x+a)}b}_{\to f'(x+a)}-2\underbrace{\dfrac{f(x+b)-f(x)}b}_{\to f'(x)}+\underbrace{\dfrac{f(x+a)-f(x)}b}_{\to\infty}$

So unless $f$ is constant, the last term diverges since you take the $\lim\limits_{b\to 0}$ first in the original expression, so I don't think this is a well formed expression.

*Note: you can try to apply to $f(x)=x$*

It would make more sense to replace $-2f(x+b)$ by $-f(x+b)-f(x+a)$ and comparing it to $f''(x)$.

Comment: This idea is used when proving the Grunwalk-Letkinov derivative (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grünwald-Letnikov_derivative) and they mentioned that this step is done by assuming that both 'a' and 'b' converge synchronously and can be justified by MVT. If possible could you explain that? and how would I use MVT to justify this.